# Website fast in Firefox, Mediocre in Internet Explorer and slow in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

As the title suggests, my website works how I want it to work in Firefox: when I use arrow down, it doesn't flicker. But this functionality isn't such in IE and Chrome. Is there a resolution to this? The website is as follows: [Contrabang](http://contrabang.com). Thank you advance for your help.

HTML is as follows:

```
            <section class="main">

             <div class="icons">
              <a class="twitter" target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/kadeemlaurie"></a>
              <a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Contrabang/127379984089682"></a>
              <a class="googleplus" target="_blank" href="http://googleplus.com/pages"></a>
             </div>

            <div id="wrap">
              <div id="featured">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <div class="textwidget">
                    <div class="cup">
                      <img src="../Contrabang/img/red-cup.png" height="200" alt="red-cup">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div id="theFixed"><h1>CONTRABANG</a></h1></div>

            <div class="bg1">

              <hgroup class="billboard second">
                <h2 style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 1; font-family: 'dosis'">
             We are an events management agency based in London. We create memorable experiences. Check out our upcoming event.</h2>

            </hgroup>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="pad">
             <a href="events"> <img src="../Contrabang/img/Contrabang.jpg"  width="300" height="400" alt="contrabang"></a>
            </div>
                <h2 style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 1; font-family: 'dosis'">
             Buy Tickets: 07949747971</h2>
            </div>


            </div>

            </section>
```

& the main CSS

```
                  .main{text-align:center;}

                  #featured {
                    background: #E94F78 url(http://www.contrabang.com/Contrabang/img/bubbles.png) no-repeat top;

                    background-size: 385px 465px;
                    color: #fff;
                    height: 535px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    position: relative;
                    z-index: -2;
                  }


                  #featured .wrap {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    clear: both;
                    padding: 70px 0 30px;
                    position: fixed;
                    z-index: -1;
                    width: 100%;
                  }


                  #featured .wrap .widget {
                    width: 80%;
                    max-width: 1040px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                  }

                  .textwidget{
                    padding: 0;
                  }


                  #wrap {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    padding: 0;
                  }

                  .cup{

                    margin-top:210px;
                  }


                  body, h1, h2, h3, p {
                    margin: 0; 
                    padding: 0;
                  }

                  a { 
                    text-decoration: none;

                  }

                  a img { border: 0; }


                  #theFixed{
                    position:fixed;
                    background-image:url(http://www.contrabang.com/Contrabang/img/leopard-print.jpg);
                    width:100%;
                    text-align:center;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    background-position: center;

                  }


                  h1{
                    font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
                    font-size:3.125em;
                    text-align:center;
                    padding:10px 10px;
                    margin:20px 20px;
                    background-color:#E94F78;
                    padding-left: 0.15em;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    display:inline-block;
                    letter-spacing: 6px;
                    padding-left: 0.15em;
                    color:yellow;

                  }

                  h1 a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    letter-spacing: 8px;
                    padding-left: 0.15em;
                    color:yellow;

                  }

                  .bg1{
                  background-image:url(http://www.contrabang.com/Contrabang/img/grey-background.jpg);
                    width: 100%;
                    height:900px;

                    background-color: #e94f78;}

                  h2{

                  font-family: georgia;
                  font-size:3em;
                    color:black;
                  }


                  .billboard {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    width: 960px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                      text-align: center;
                  }

                  .pad{
                    padding:20px;
                  }


                  .billboard a {
                    color: #000000;   
                  }


                  .billboard {
                    padding-top:230px;
                  }
```

Comment: A little tip about your fonts. Load your Google Fonts fil before you load your main css file. Then you can define the elements you want to use the Google Font in your main style sheet rather than doing it via inline styles which is bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

That Rita Ora image is almost 4mb in size. I'd hazard a guess that that's your culprit right there.

I'd suggest doing some reading up on optimising images for use on the web.

That image should be about 30/40k at most.